# The time complexity of the for loop nested with if-statement and while loop

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```cpp
void makeGraph(){
    for(auto itr = inputs.begin(); itr != inputs.end(); itr++){
        string str = itr->second;
        if (strstr(str.c_str(), "->") != NULL){
            char ch = '>';
            size_t pos = str.find_last_of(ch);
            parent = str.substr(0, pos-2);
            string child = str.substr(pos+2);
            if (strstr(parent.c_str(), ",") != NULL){
                int size_parent = parent.length();
                char ch_parent[size_parent+1];
                strcpy(ch_parent, parent.c_str());
                char *token = strtok(ch_parent, ",");
                while (token != NULL){
                    string sub_Parent = token;
                    sub_Parent.erase(std::remove(sub_Parent.begin(),
                                                 sub_Parent.end(),
                                                 ' '),
                                     sub_Parent.end());
                    graph[sub_Parent].push_back(child);
                    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                }
            } else{
                graph[parent].push_back(child);
            }
        } else{
            cout<<"Just for TEST"<<endl;
        }
    }
    printGraph();
}
```

What is the time complexity of this function? Is it n O(n)?? How do you handle the loop inside the else statement?

Comment: To get a rough idea, run this code for varying values of *N* and see what curve is a best fit. `N = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... }` is usually enough. In general a loop within a loop where both are a function of *N* means you have *O(N^2)* at least.

Comment: The real question here is why you're bashing around with C strings in the middle of C++ code using `std::string`.

Comment: @tadman Yes, that's right, but now I do not want an exact answer, I just want to estimate.

Comment: Estimate: Run for various values of N. Done. If it's quadratic you'll find out *fast*, and by fast I mean you'll quit the test because it's taking ages.

Comment: @tadman ok, I run it for various values of N. thank you.

Comment: @tadman I did not catch it " bashing with C strings in the middle of c++ code". Can you explain that?

Comment: There's really no reason to drop down to dirty C strings in the middle of some C++ code, especially not just to use `strtok()`. Remember, C++ has [regular expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), so steer towards solutions in that domain rather than going back to the 1970s.

Comment: What is N? as you have a list of pair, size of the string from that list, (operations on string/map/vector)...

Comment: @Jarod42 I have a map of vectors. Inputs are stored as strings in the vector.

Comment: Is this an academic homework question, and if so at what level, otherwise what sort of application you have in mind for this code? Remember that computational complexity is a theoretical measure that may wildly differ from results you see in actual use for "small" datasets, and these days small datasets may be much bigger than one thinks, since the CPUs are just quite good at operating on data so lots of things are dependent mostly on memory access and not what computations you actually perform. Computation is often "free" - fully amortized in memory latency.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica No, this is not an academic homework question. I am learning C ++ and I want to know how to calculate time complexity when the code is very complex. Is there a way other than running?

Comment: @simsim I've gone through and formatted your code consistently. In the future, please try to format code to make it as readable as possible. At the very least, use consistent indentation.
On another note, empty character literals don't exist in C++, so this expression isn't valid: `std::remove(sub_Parent.begin(), sub_Parent.end(), '')`. Hence the odd highlighting going on. You might want to think about what that expression is meant to be doing. As it is, I think the answer to your question is "could be anything because code not valid".

Comment: @simsim Going back to Jarod's question ("What is N?"). You're code has multiple ways in which the inputs could scale, and therefore there are at least these variables you need to account for:
1. The number of elements in `input`.
2. The size of the strings stored in `input`.
Are you assuming the strings are constant-bounded, and so focusing only on the size of `input`? Or perhaps the other way around? If both can scale independently, you need to use multiple variables (M, N) to determine its complexity.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde I used this line of code only to remove extra spaces in the string. In the questions asked here(i mean stack overflow), many people suggested this way remove spaces in the string.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde Yes, I know that scales such as string size and the number of inputs should be considered to calculate time complexity. But if in such a situation the number of inputs and the size of the strings is not known, can it be estimated?

Comment: So sounds like `''` is meant to be `' '` instead? Regarding estimates, I think I have enough context now to write up a proper answer.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty in this case is that you have many variables that need to be accounted for. The important one being:

1. The number of elements in `input`.
2. For each string in `input`, the number of characters in the string.

If you want a precise estimate, you would have to separately account for each of these variables. If we use `N` to refer to the length of `input`, then we have `N` strings whose lengths are `M1`, `M2`, ..., `MN`. Each string can be handled differently, so that complicates things as well.

Since Big-O provides an upper bound, we can save ourself some trouble by instead considering these variables:

1. `N`, being the number of elements in `input`.
2. `M`, being the length of the longest input string.

The last big simplification comes from looking at the worst case behaviour. Without know more about the input data, we can't really do more nuanced calculation anyways, so let's just do the worst case.

Since there is so much going on here, I like to look at the "leaves" - the most nested blocks - and then work my way up. Let's hone in on the elephant in the room: the `while` loop. What's going on here? The loop itself is basically just iterating over `parent`. Note that the length of `parent` can scale linearly with the length of `str`, which means the complexity of the `while` loop will look like `O(M * [complexity of the while body])`. The body is only composed of a few steps:

```
string sub_Parent = token;
sub_Parent.erase(std::remove(sub_Parent.begin(), sub_Parent.end(), ' '), sub_Parent.end());
graph[sub_Parent].push_back(child);
token = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

The work involving `sub_Parent` and `token` plays into the looping behaviour of the `while` loop (i.e., the fewer `while` loop iterations there are, the longer `token` will generally be, and vice versa). However, none of those operations will scale worse than `O(M)` since the length of `parent` is itself `O(M)`. Instead let's focus on the `push_back()` call. Since the length of `child` is `O(M)`, and since this `push_back()` copies `child`, this operation is `O(M)` in time complexity. Therefore, we can confidently say that the complexity of the while loop body is `O(M)` as well. Combining the body with the loop itself, the total complexity of the while loop is:

```
  O(M * [complexity of the while body]
= O(M * M)
= O(M^2)
```

Now let's go up one level. The operations outside of the `while` loop are clearly `O(M)` since they deal with copying and searching `parent`. The `while` loop dominates this, so we can ignore those contributions.

Going up one more level, we hit the `if`. What do we do here? Well, in the `true` case, we get the `while` loop with complexity `O(M^2)`. In the `false` case, we get a `push_back()` with a copy of `child`, making that `O(M)`. Since we're looking at the worst case, we'll say the complexity of the `if`/`else` is the larger expression: `O(M^2)`.

Going up another level (just outside the `if` from the previous step), we have a similar situation as before in that the operations are at worst `O(M)` as they search and copy `str` to create `parent` and `child`. These are dominated by the `if` complexity, so we can ignore their contributions.

Now for the outermost `if`. We again compare branches. In the `true` branch, we have the `O(M^2)` complexity we just worked out. In the `false` branch we have `O(1)` complexity (just printing a constant string). So in the worst case, this `if` has `O(M^2)` complexity.

We're almost there. Outside of that `if` we have a copy to create `str`. This is `O(M)`, so we can ignore it as it is dominated by the `O(M^2)` from the `if`. So the `for` loop body is `O(M^2)` in total.

Finally we look at the `for` loop itself. It is a simple linear iteration over `input` (being `N` elements in length), meaning its complexity is:

```
  O(N * [complexity of the body])
= O(N * M^2)
```

So there you have it. The worst case complexity is linear in the length of `input`, but quadratic in the length of the longest string.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. You explained very well. Thank you very much.